# How would you interpret the sentence "他人と違って家族の縁はなかなか切れない。"?

Tags: interpretation

1) I find hard to cut ties with my familly but other people find it easy (to cut ties with their family)

2)I find hard to cut ties with my family but I find easy to cut ties with other people

3)other

(there is no context, this is an example sentence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can't easily cut ties with your family the way you can with others.

Notice that the topic (は) is 家族の縁, not an omitted 私 (or other).  So then the 他人 is contrasted with 家族, not with "me".  It would be clearer if it was stated as 他人の縁, but the の縁 would be redundant, so it is left out there.  So a more literal translation would be

> Ties with your family cannot be easily broken compared to (ties with) others.

Although I feel like this question will still be closed...